# Wordpress plugin installation not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-bookings

I am trying to setup a wordpress project locally on my Kubuntu, using Apache2. I have already installed Woocommerce, and i want to add Woocommerce Bookings, so i've downloaded the zip.

Quoting the documentation :

> Download the .zip file from your WooCommerce account. Go to: WordPress
>   Admin > Plugins > Add New to upload the file you downloaded. Activate
>   the extension.

I've tried to do this, and i have this error :

> Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2017/04. Is its parent
>   directory writable by the server?

So I've tried to change the apache directory to set it on my /home/user, chmod 765 -R / chown user -R / chgrp -R the directory, and it still doesn't work. I've also tried to set the content of the zip archive in the plugins folder, but still nothing. Also tried to create myself the uploads/2017/04 folder, but i have a similar error (cannot copy the content).

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions

Answer (score 0):

Open wp-config.php file and add `define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');`
Then make server writable the directories wp-content/, wp-content/plugins/.
now install the plugin (copy the plugin into wp-content/plugins folder).